# html content type data:image/png:Base64,

Tags: html, web

I have a link /1/, when I put it into brower address bar (remmeber to remove single quotation at the beginning and at the end). It is a image/png picture.

Now I want to show this picture by jetty comet feature by pushing to client. I have a js, part of codes is in /2/, then in the client page/browser(firefox and chrome), I could not see picture, but raw data. In web.xml, I already put mime type /3/. Could any expert drop me some hints how to show picture when sending data from server to client?

/1/Please remove single quotation at the begining and at the end of block

```
data:image/png;base64,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`
```

/2/put into inner html,

```
symbolDiv.innerHTML='data:image/png;base64,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';
```

/3/

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.cometd.annotation.AnnotationCometdServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>transports</param-name>
        <param-value>org.cometd.websocket.server.WebSocketTransport</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>org.cometd.tutorials.StockPriceService</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>maxLazyTimeout</param-name>
        <param-value>2000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>initializer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.cometd.tutorials.Initializer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>png</extension>
    <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a URL to an image (albeit one where the image is embedded in the URL itself). Set it as the value of a `src` attribute on an `img` element.